# HttpClient times out when changing from 3G to WiFi

Tags: android

I perform some large downloads. I start a download being connected to 3G, all is fine. Then, I switch to WiFi connection, but the request returns a timeout exception. I have used HttpClient library. I have implemented a retry mechanism, so, when the request returns an exception, it sleeps for 0.5 seconds and tries to execute again and again. I would expect that, after connecting to a WiFi, the Http request could execute. But it seems that the Http execute method returns a null response, all the time after that. Very strange, if I commute again to 3G, the execute method returns again a good response. Can anyone help me please :) ?

Comment: in fact, it returns a Socket exception, not a null response

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, it seems that it may be more convenient to use [DownloadManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html) for large files - it handles retry and everything.

As for HttpClient - it's known to have some issues, but i'm not sure if you bumped into one of them or just overlooked something. It's been deprecated as of Gingerbread, you may want to try HttpUrlConnection instead, it's said to have less problems than HttpClient.

Also, when switching between WIFI and cell connections, HttpClient may need to be reinitialized completely, there's [http range header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35) to tell server which byte you want to continue downloading from. But again, I suggest you give DownloadManager a try, it may save you a lot of time.

Comment: My issue is similar, but I am not downloading large files, only small ones and I get exception when changing from 3G to Wifi or vice versa. I have also tried to shutdown connection manager after every request and recreated httpclient, but still same problem existing.

Comment: Also when using WebView for opening url, first with Wifi it works, then when changing to 3G, my application cannot open second url with WebView, so this seems to be platform bug.

Comment: Hmm, yeah, with WebView also not being able to use 3G this looks far more serious than just misusing HttpClient. WebView uses native call to load urls. Hm... just to be sure - is 3G available on your data plan? :) Are you able to load anything on 3G with aosp or 3rd party browser apps? There's also configuration to be checked (Acess Point, etc). My guess is the device might think it's connected to cell internet but the actual traffic may not come through if AP is not right or your operator doesn't allow 3G.

Comment: WebView is able to load the page with 3G but not if something has been loaded before that with Wifi. And one more notice that with ICS this cannot be reproduced, so definitely platform bug.

Comment: Well, you've got to work around it somehow. Does AOSP browser handle this case well?

Comment: ICS works fine, but older devices not, reinitializing/restarting/destroying httpclient and manager doesn't help.

Comment: Does native browser on older devices handle this scenario well? 'Cause if it doesn't you can safely assume it's a platform issue.

Comment: WebView doesn't work either which uses native implementation, so we decided to leave it as it is, must be because of platform.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a routing problem: 
when switching between different network types usually the local ip address and, more important, the local routing table changes, due to a different gateway being used. This means that packages that traveled fine between client and server wont reach any destination after a network change, if they are send the same route. Most likely your client implementation has to be notified of the change or even restartet completely, so that the routing strategy is reinitilized.

If the documentation of the implementation components you use dont reveal anything you could try to track this down using a package sniffer like wireshark. Typically packages running into nirwhana show up easily there.